# Do gravitational waves travel on geodesics in GR? If yes, why?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

I think, the answer is probably yes, but it can be answered by somebody who knows GR much better than I do.

In case of a positive answer, can we say that gravitational radiation will be bent around graviting bodies exactly as light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, gravitational waves travel along light-like geodesics, and short-wavelength gravitational radiation will be bent around gravitating bodies just like light.  For details, see chapter 35, "Propagation of Gravitational Waves" in Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, especially section 35.14, "Effect of Background Curvature on Wave Propagation", exercise 35.15, "Geometric Optics", and exercise 35.17, "Gravitational Deflection of Gravitational Waves".

Comment: I thought that is restricted to only weak waves. At least my Landau&Lifshitz told me so.

Comment: @firtree Well, yes, gravitational waves in general are analyzed as being a small perturbation of some background metric.  If the wave is too large, the nonlinear effects become non-negligible and the analysis becomes inaccurate.  I'm assuming that the question is asking about sufficiently weak waves.  In practice, gravitational waves that e.g. we might hope to detect with LIGO are so weak that they haven't even been able to detect one yet.